# Enumerative geometry and restricted plane partitions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, enumerative-combinatorics, string-theory, enumerative-geometry

[Donaldson-Thomas theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.00779) is an enumerative theory for virtual counts of ideal sheaves (with trivial determinant) of the structural sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ of some smooth projective manifold $X$.

There is a well-known relation between this theory and the enumerative counting of [plane partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition) when $X$ is a toric Calabi-Yau threefold. The statement for $X$ = $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ = $ Spec(\mathbb{C}[z_{1},z_{2}$, $z_{3}])$ says that the Donaldson-Thomas theory counts toric-equivariant monomials in $z_{1},z_{2}$ and $z_{3}$ (as explained in the page 50 of [Takagi lectures on Donaldson-Thomas theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.00779)). The miraculous fact comes from the fact that there is a bijection between any of the aforementioned monomials and the set of all plane partitions stacked at the origin of $\mathbb{Z}^{3}$; to see the bijection we simply identify every box in a given plane partition with a point in $\mathbb{Z}^{3}$ and apply the following map $$z_{1}^{a}z_{2}^{b}z_{3}^{c} \mapsto (a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^{3}.$$

Now consider the combinatorics of restricted partitions (plane partitions that are stacked above some rectangle of size $N\times M$  where $N$ and $M$ are not simultaneously infinite as the ones from below) as studied in the page 117 of [(1)](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/crt.pdf).

[image]

This problem has also appeared in gauge theory (see [(2)](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0607032) and [(3)](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0409270)) in a rather similar way as the counting of ordinary plane partitions has appeared in gauge theory [(4)](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312022).

**Question:**

**What is the algebro-geometric interpretation of the counting of restricted partitions?**